# R: Loop through data frame, extract subset of multiple variables, then store in an aggregate dataset

Tags: r

I have an aggregate data table with about 60 million rows. Simplified, the data looks like this:

```
ServiceN  Customer  Product  LValue  EDate  CovBDate  CovEDate
1   1   12  3    2016-08-03 2016-07-07 2017-07-06
2   1   12  19   2016-07-07 2016-07-07 2017-07-06
3   2   23  222  2017-09-09 2016-10-01 2017-09-31
4   2   23  100  2017-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-09-31
```

I need to go through each row and subset the entire dataset by Customer with all entry dates(EDate) between CovBDate and CovEDate. Then, I need to find the sum of the LValue for each product (we're only looking at 10, so it's not terrible).

As an example, the final dataset would look something like this:

```
ServiceN  Customer  Product  LValue  EDate  CovBDate  CovEDate Prod12 Prod23
1   1   12  3    2016-08-03 2016-07-07 2017-07-06  22  0
2   1   12  19   2016-07-07 2016-07-07 2017-07-06  22  0
3   2   23  222  2017-09-09 2016-10-01 2017-09-31  0   222
4   2   23  100  2017-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-09-31  0   100
```

I don't know where to begin on this problem, however, I've started with this (which does not work):

```
for (i in 1:length(nrow)) {
  tempdata<-dataset[Customer==Customer[i] & EDate>=CovBDate[i] & 
  EDate<=CovEDate[i]] #data.table subsetting
  tempdata$Prod12<- with(tempdata, sum(LValue[Product== "12"], na.rm=T))
  #I could make this a function, but I want to get this for loop automated first...
  tempdata$Prod23<- with(tempdata, sum(LValue[Product=="23"], na.rm=T))
}
```

My questions, therefore, are:
1) How do I make this for loop work with so many variables?
2) How do I make the new variable get added to the original dataset (called dataset)?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` you could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset <- data.frame(ServiceN = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
    Customer = c("1", "1", "2", "2"),
    Product = c("12", "12", "23", "23"),
    LValue = c(3, 19, 222, 100),
    EDate  = c("2016-08-03", "2016-07-07", "2017-09-09", "2017-10-01"),
    CovBDate = c("2016-07-07", "2016-07-07", "2016-10-01", "2017-10-01"),
    CovEDate = c("2017-07-06", "2017-07-06", "2017-09-31", "2018-09-31"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Group by customer and product so summary results are per-customer/product combination
dataset %>% group_by(Customer, Product) %>%
    ## Filter based on dates
    filter(EDate >= CovBDate & EDate <= CovEDate) %>%
    ## Sum the LValue based on the defined groupings
    summarise(Sum = sum(LValue))


## A tibble: 2 x 3
## Groups:   Customer [?]
# Customer Product   Sum
#<chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
#1 1        12         22
#2 2        23        322
```

Comment: I need the code to subset the data for dates/Customer/Product in each row (so if there's 60M rows, there's 60M subsets of data). So each row has its own subset for which the line value is summed.

Comment: Did you try to run my code? In what way did it not accomplish your goal? Can you supply sample data in an easy-to-read format?

Comment: Could you then supply sample data using (eg) `dput`?

Comment: I did run the code you posted. In the console, it says # A tibble: 0x3 #Groups: Customer [?]...with 3 variables: Customer <chr>, Product <chr>, Sum<dbl>.  I'm not familiar with dplyr, so I looked up whether the variable class matters, but that doesn't seem to matter in that the output isn't changing... I'll get a sample dataset and post.

Comment: See my update, the code I posted runs fine on the data you provided.